# Running stored procedures of a SQL server from c++ code

Tags: c++, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a database in SQL server and have already created stored procedures which run on the data stored in this database. The client code of this databse is a native c++ windows service code. what I need is simple, connecting to the sql server from my c++ code, run the stored procedures ( sending the input parameters and getting the output) and closing the connection. How can I do this?

I found many solutions for connecting to db from c++ code but they are all based on some framework ( .Net, MFC, or some other managed c++ etc...) but my code is pure native legacy cpp code written in VS 2005 and for some compatibility reasons need to stay as it is.

I really appriciate any comments/ hints.

Comment: Standard c++ doesn't provide any functionality to do that. You would need to implement all of the SQL-Server protocol commands yourself, or find an appropriate library that does that for you.

Comment: what is the SQL server version?

Comment: SQL server version is 2012

Answer (score 1):

Use the SQL Server Native Client. This is a native library that provides OLE DB access to SQL Server. The client library itself is based on COM (as befits its object-oriented design):

This page provides a straightforward example of how to connect to a database server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131323.aspx

And this page describes (though without giving an example) how to execute a command: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131427.aspx

A class and interface reference is provided here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711625(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks! I will check these out